# Google Maps API area of polygon

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, geometry

I am trying to find the area of the polygon. This occurs on the loading of the polygon and will be used in functions. Here is my code :

```
  map.data.forEach(function(feature) {
    if (feature.getGeometry().getType() == "Polygon") {
        var bounds=[];
        feature.getGeometry().forEachLatLng(function(path) {
          var temp = new google.maps.LatLng(path.lat,path.lng);
          bounds.push(temp);

        });
        console.log(bounds);
        console.log(google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeArea(bounds));

    }
});
```

if the loaded object is a polygon, it makes an array of LatLngs and then it should use the computeArea function. I keep getting a NaN returned from this. I looked at the help docs and compute area takes in an area of latLngs, which is what bounds is.

Bounds displays correctly, so I am not sure why the area is not being calculated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`.forEachLatLng`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Data) function returns a [`google.maps.LatLng`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#LatLng).  That doesn't have `.lat` and `.lng` properties (and you don't need to convert it to a `google.maps.LatLng`, it already is one), those are **functions**.

This works for me:

```
map.data.forEach(function(feature) {
    if (feature.getGeometry().getType() == "Polygon") {
        var bounds=[];
        feature.getGeometry().forEachLatLng(function(path) {
          bounds.push(path);
        });
        console.log(bounds);
        console.log(google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeArea(bounds));
    }
});
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/Ltpfpb5g/2/)

**code snippet:**

```js
function initialize() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
      zoom: 4,
      center: {
        lat: -28,
        lng: 137
      },
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
  map.data.loadGeoJson(
    'https://storage.googleapis.com/mapsdevsite/json/google.json', {},
    function(features) {

      map.data.forEach(function(feature) {
        if (feature.getGeometry().getType() == "Polygon") {
          var bounds = [];
          var polyBnds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

          feature.getGeometry().forEachLatLng(function(path) {
            bounds.push(path);
            polyBnds.extend(path);
          });
          console.log(bounds);
          var area = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeArea(bounds);
          console.log(area);
          var iW = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: area.toFixed(2) + " sq meters",
            position: polyBnds.getCenter()
          });
          iW.open(map);
        }
      });
    });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=geometry&key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk"></script>
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
```